# Gesture: Failed to receive system gesture state notification before next touch

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

What causes this warning?

> Gesture: Failed to receive system gesture state notification before
>   next touch iOS 8.1

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue and am trying to figure out whats up with it. Currently, I can only produce it when I tap like a crazy person, my issue is that it will crash shortly after.

Comment: Currently getting this and wondering myself... same thing: Need to tap like a madman to get it to happen, but it happens nonetheless :P

Comment: I have the same and it's on empty app with new iPad Pro 13inch ((     <_UISystemGestureGateGestureRecognizer: 0x28127c1e0>: Gesture: Failed to receive system gesture state notification before next touch
2019-06-11 18:04:53.863817+0300 [4607:1012555] <_UISystemGestureGateGestureRecognizer: 0x28127c1e0>: Gesture: Failed to receive system gesture state notification before next touch

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it just means that you're overloading the system with too many gestures. Its not a problem, just means that you are for instance swiping too much or tapping the screen too quickly. The system was not able to process the previous gesture before the next gesture was done.